# Recording and charting boot process information in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I need to write a command line tool that records the boot process information in Linux, and then renders it in a chart format (a textual chart would do). How do I programmatically obtain the this boot process information? Languages that I am allowed to use are C and C++.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: What would you describe as "boot process information"? kernel loading messages? init script progress/messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't [link text][1] pretty much already do this? Or do you need to write an initlog replacement?

I don't know what kind of "chart" you would make from such data, but have a look at gnuplot to help you with that part.

edit: I had the wrong tool mentioned originally.

[1]: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_initlog.htm initlog

Comment: Well, it's a homework assignment and I can't show an existing app to my professor. :-/

Comment: Not really, but if that app does what you need, you could take a look at the code (if it is open)

Answer (score 1):

You could look at bootchart http://www.bootchart.org/ that seems to be something that already does exactly what you want.

Comment: This is a homework assignment. I can't show an existing app to my professor. :-/

Comment: you could look at how it picks up the information couldn't you?